# how to remove password authentication in ubuntu software center?

Tags: software-center

I am new to ubuntu.Frequent password authentication while downloading any software in ubuntu is frustrating.Is there any way to remove it ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a security feature that is best left as-is but if it really bugs you here is a link

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18222/how-to-prevent-system-applications-like-the-software-center-from-asking-for-pa

Comment: This authentication is not for downloading software, but for installing software. It is base security principle. There is no need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to agree with the others on here. Having password authentication for installing software is a 'security feature'. What this does is ensure that you are explicitly intending to install the software. Rather than with Windows, for example, that will auto-install things for you, some of which could contain adware and other malicious add-ons. Linux ensures that you aren't installing something without having that explicit consent (aka: password authentication). I highly recommend not trying to bypass this feature.