# Convert Ubuntu to _not_ using sudo

Tags: password, sudo, root

I've searched this forum but not found an answer.

I've a user that uses sudo
I've set a root password so I can use su

What I would like to do is remove the use of sudo, so that the system asks for the root password, as Debian does.

I *know* Ubuntu is set up for using sudo
I *don't want* to be explained why sudo is supposed to be better than su, I've read this a thousand time and I prefer su.

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to convert Ubuntu to using su or if it's impossible. I know Debian gives you the choice when you install but I don't know if once the choice is done it's final (although I think because it's Linux it can be done).

I simply find it confusing with both sudo and su because I never know which "password" is asked.

If I simply remove my user from the sudoers I can still use root, but I'm no more asked for the password when a program needs it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent system applications (like the Software Center) from asking for password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18222/how-to-prevent-system-applications-like-the-software-center-from-asking-for-pa)

Comment: Well, set both passwords to the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

You could add

`Defaults        targetpw`

to your sudoers file. This will result in sudo asking you for the password of the target user (i.e. root)